# How to save data frame or matrix as raw r input code?

Tags: r

I'm sure this is a really stupid question and there's a really simple answer but I was wondering if there was a way to be able to get a data table in R turned into a code that would input that raw data. I am trying to figure this out because I have another stupid question but the data generation part is so long and uses a bunch of different packages and it doesn't have anything to do with my question but I still need to show the data table to ask the question and give an example code so trying to figure out how to easily put that into a raw r data code should help.

What I mean by raw R code is like if you were to input data manually into R so that way I could just share that code instead of the 100 other lines and all the libraries used to generate that code.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: `dput()` function might do what you have in mind.

Comment: Yes that works thank you so much! Edit: Also sorry I don't have enough rep to up vote you or at least I don't see that option. :(